Spring-Batch-Application Returns the oracle sessionID as 0
I am new to java spring batch application, and I am trying to get the database sessionID from oracle through JAVA and somehow the value always returns as 0. Any idea what might be causing this?
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSIONID') AS sessionid FROM dual

The above query always returns as 0. But if I run the query in my sqlplus I get the sessionID perfectly.
